# best way to slice even/odd indexes from a python array?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a card game program.

So far I have created the array called 'deck' which comprises of 30 Cards numbered 1 to 30, where each has been allocated a colour 'RED', 'BLACK' or 'YELLOW'

My task is for the first player to take the first card of the deck and for the second player to take the second card of the deck consecutively until there are no more cards left in the array 'deck'

So I thought that the best way to do this is for player1 to get all the even number of indexes from the deck (0,2,4,6...28) and for player2 to get every odd number of indexes from the deck (1,3,5,7...29)

What would be the best way to do this?

I have tried to use the the filter built in method to retrieve even or odd indexes but I feel that this is incorrect

```py
import random 
colours = ['RED','BLACK','YELLOW']
deck = [(random.randint(1,31),random.choice(colours)) for _ in range(30)]
deck = random.shuffle(deck)
print(deck)

def Player1_Cards(deck):
    Player1_Cards = list(filter(deck[::2]))
    return Player1_Cards

def Player2_Cards(deck):
    Player2_Cards = list(filter(deck[::1]))

    return Player2_Cards

print(Player1_Cards(deck))
print(Player2_Cards(deck))

#The output is "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"
```

Comment: `deck[::2]` and `deck[1::2]` are already the lists you're looking for, you don't need to use `filter`

Comment: random.shuffle(deck) don't returns anything. So, it can't be assigned to any variable. random.shuffle() actually changes the content of the list passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way to asssign 15 random non-repitive numbers to both players from 1 to 30 would be-

```
import random 

def Player1_Cards(deck):
    return deck[:16]

def Player2_Cards(deck):
    return deck[16:]


colours = ['RED','BLACK','YELLOW']
deck = list(range(1,31))
random.shuffle(deck)
print('Randomized Deck:\n',deck)

print('Player 1:',Player1_Cards(deck))
print('Player 2:',Player2_Cards(deck))
```

Comment: If you think this answer is helpful and worked perfectly, please mark it as Answered so that others will not get confused with whether they have to answer it or not. :)